# Rails - How to submit a form without changing the page and updating the view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, stimulusjs

*Hello all !*

Im using rails and in the steps I would like the user to (on the same page) :

1. Enter his address
   [Filling the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pABHw.png)
2. Submit the form
   [Click to submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfsE7.png)
3. Update the view to show the address
   [The view updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAHWg.png)

Should I use Stimulis or Ajax? I don’t quite understand which would be more useful!
Because i try to use simply JS but it’s was not DRY and not really simple:

```
// file.js

document.querySelector(".form").addEventListener('submit', function () {
  adress_form = document.querySelector(".adress_form");
  adress_form.style.display="none";
  document.location.reload();
  display_adress = document.querySelector(".display_adress");
  display_adress.style.display = "block";
});
```

```
#file.html.erb

<div class="display_adress">
  <% if current_user.line1? && current_user.postal_code? && current_user.city? %>
    <p>Mon adresse actuel : <%= current_user.line1 %>, <%= current_user.city %> <%= current_user.postal_code %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="address_form">
  <%= simple_form_for(current_user, remote: true, html: { id: "addddd"}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :line1, label: 'Mon adresse' %>
  <%= f.input :city, label: 'Ville' %>
  <%= f.input :postal_code, label: 'Code Postal' %>
  <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**To resume, i want the user to enter his address on the form, to submit, to update my database and to update the view with the new address the user submitted**

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can respond in the controller javascript. For example:
`file.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for(current_user, remote: true, format: :js, html: { id: "addddd"}) do |f| %>
```

`users_controller.rb`

```
def create
  # do your business logic
  render 'create
end
```

`users/create.js.erb`

```
document.getElementById("formId").innerText = "Othe html text or you can call render(*)"
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Деревянко Сергей ! It works but if i want to update (or create) my user in a another view with another fields, the js created in users/create.js.erb will be called again :/ Moreover the information is not persistent when i refresh manually the page... There is a solution to that problem ? :)

Comment: You want to make dynamic front-end(spa pages, backend requests)  on the traditioanal back-end. Best practices for that is develop separatly front(react, vue, angular, etc) and beckend(rest-api, graphql, etc). Implementing like that on the traditional backend is very difficult and confused, and requires providing special libs(react on rails or something else), and if you want make similar requests to the one point(updating user for example) you should coding it in the api_controllers